# Regex on string containg escape characters

Tags: python, regex

I have a function that is passed a Linux filename, as a string, which could look like:

```
\home\test\2015-11-11\part2\part2a\part2b.png     or
\test1\test2\test3\test4\test5\2016-01-01\c\test3\test4.bin    or
\opt\logging\bin64\spare\1905-12-12\intereting\file\location\part2.txt
```

As you can see from my two file name examples the location of the date is variable.

Python version is 2.7

I'm only interested in the part of the string after the date field. My idea was to use regex to find the location with something like

```
re.search( "\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}_\d{5}", file_in ).end()
```

however the presence of \2 in the string causes the regex to fail.

In a standalone test, if I

```
filename = r'\home\test\2015-11-11\part2\part2a\part2b'
```

the regex will work as it's working on a raw string, however in my real program, the passed filename is not in raw format and I can't find a way to convert it, that works, i.e. that copes with `\2` etc.

Is there another approach to finding where my date?

Comment: A Linux filename should be forward slash separated.  E.g. /home/test/2015-11-11/part2/part2a/part2b.png
Where are you getting these file names from?

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure what the problem is... your regex can't work, because (1) there is no `_` in the string, and (2) the part after the date is not just digits.

If you make the regex a raw string, you can use `\\` to match the `\` in the string (or `\\\\` without `r`), and `(.*?)` to ensure that only the next segment is captured (non-greedy).

This regex should work: `r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\\(.*?)\\'`

```
>>> lst
['\\home\\test\\2015-11-11\\part2\\part2a\\part2b.png',
 '\\test1\\test2\\test3\\test4\\test5\\2016-01-01\\c\\test3\\test4.bin',
 '\\opt\\logging\\bin64\\spare\\1905-12-12\\intereting\\file\\location\\part2.txt']
>>> [re.search(r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\\(.*?)\\', s).group(1) for s in lst]
['part2', 'c', 'intereting']
```

Note that a "raw" string (`r'...'`) only makes sense when the string is entered directly in the source code. If this is the case, just add the `r` prefix to the string. If the string comes from some other place, from a file or from a textfield in a UI, backslashes will automatically be properly escaped.

Also, as already noted, path separators on Linux should actually be `/`, not `\`.

```
>>> lst2 = [s.replace('\\', '/') for s in lst]
>>> [re.search(r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/(.*?)/', s).group(1) for s in lst2]
['part2', 'c', 'intereting']
```

Answer (score 0):

By the time you are applying your regex then the string has probably already been corrupted.  The solution is probably to replace the backslashes with double backslashes before you get the data.

However, Linux filenames should not contain backslashes, and should be forward slash separate (e.g. `/home/test/2015-11-11/part2/part2a/part2b.png`).  If you can convert them into this format before you receive the data then you will be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

What about this just prepending `r`-

```
import re


data = [r'\home\test\2015-11-11\part2\part2a\part2b.png',
r'\test1\test2\test3\test4\test5\2016-01-01\c\test3\test4.bin',
r'\opt\logging\bin64\spare\1905-12-12\intereting\file\location\part2.txt']


def date_finder(s):
    return re.findall(r'(?<=(?<=\\)(?:\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})(?=\\))(.*)',i)

for i in data:
    print date_finder(i)
```

Output-

```
['\\part2\\part2a\\part2b.png']
['\\c\\test3\\test4.bin']
['\\intereting\\file\\location\\part2.txt']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [raw string](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) if you need backslashes in it (Anyway, it can't end with a single backslash!). But in Linux, path folders are separated by forward slashes

Example:

```
re.compile(r'\this\is\a\path')
re.compile(r'\this\doesnt\work\')
```

If you need your string to end with a backslash you should use double backslashes everywhere

```
re.compile('\\this\\works\\now\\')
```

Or a little trick ;)

```
re.compile(r'\this\also\works'+'\\')
```

Answer (score 0):

The use of / was just a typo on my part and made worse by the example file names not having the _xxxxx data after, making the regex look wrong.

A colleague of mine had a look and seemed to think it was down to the way I was reading the string. Once I applied the very similar code to my real program it correctly finds the date field in my file name and works.

Thanks to all for the fast responses

Answer (score 0):

As you specified you only want the filename after the date....

```
import re
files=['/home/test/2015-11-11/part2/part2a/part2b.png',
'/test1/test2/test3/test4/test5/2016-01-01/c/test3/test4.bin',
'/opt/logging/bin64/spare/1905-12-12/intereting/file/location/part2.txt']

for f2 in files:
    try:
        last_file=re.split('\d{4}[-]\d{2}[-]\d{2}/',f2)[1].split('/')[-1]
    except ValueError:
        last_file="Not Found"
    print last_file,f2
```

Which will produce the output of

```
part2b.png /home/test/2015-11-11/part2/part2a/part2b.png
test4.bin /test1/test2/test3/test4/test5/2016-01-01/c/test3/test4.bin
part2.txt /opt/logging/bin64/spare/1905-12-12/intereting/file/location/part2.txt
```

Steps are:

1. Split using a Regex
2. Split again using the file delimiter
3. Take last item from array

Try/Except... because for sure not all your data will match.

Regards

Tim